# Why am I receiving an error on </script> ? the error is (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input)

Tags: javascript, arrays, error-handling, while-loop, do-loops

Basically, I am trying to create a shipping fulfillment program but i am getting an error that i can't debug myself. Thanks everyone.

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var totalPrice = 0;
            var totalVolume = 0;
            var totalItem = 0;
            var numTrucks = 0;
            var productArray = ["LT","ST","DC","LC","PR","SP","SW"]; // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
            var shippingvolumeArray = ["5.5","3","3.25","2","2.5","0.5","0.25"];
            var unitpriceArray = [1000,600,650,800,375,350,275];
            var productCode = Number(prompt("enter product code:"));
            var Quantity = prompt("enter quantity");

            do {
                var productCode = prompt("enter product code:");
                var Quantity = prompt("enter quantity:");
                for (var i = 0; i<= productArray.length; i++) {
                    if (productCode == productArray[i]) {
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + unitpriceArray[i] * Quantity;
                        totalVolume = totalVolume + shippingvolumeArray[i] + Quantity;
                        totalItem = totalItem + Quantity;
                    }
                }
                document.write(totalPrice);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `do` loop is not closed, `while` part is missing there. It should be:

```
do {
  var productCode = prompt("enter product code:");
  var Quantity = prompt("enter quantity:");
  for (var i = 0; i<= productArray.length; i++) {
    if (productCode == productArray[i]) {
      totalPrice = totalPrice + unitpriceArray[i] * Quantity;
      totalVolume = totalVolume + shippingvolumeArray[i] + Quantity;
      totalItem = totalItem + Quantity;
    }
  }
  document.write(totalPrice);
} while (something);
```

Comment: what would replace the (something)? thanks for the quick response.

Comment: could i fix by replacing Something with (i !=== 0) ?